# Index to filter a view before joining the underlying tables

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, performance, index-tuning, query-performance

Using SQL Server 2008 R2

Suppose you have a query like the following

```
select top 1 * 
from view_cms_user
where UserId = 1234 or UserPasswordRequestHash = 'anxazno121o3n'
```

view_cms_user is basically:

```
select *
from cms_user
left outer join cms_usersettings
    on cms_user.UserId = cms_usersettings.UserSettingsUserId
```

Now, the query execution plan looks like the follow: 
[image: relevant portion of execution plan]
Now, this query takes a long time because the filter happens after the join between the two tables in the view, but `cms_usersettings` actually contains both of the fields necessary to answer this question, since `UserSettingsUserId` is a foreign key field referencing `cms_user.UserId`.

I tried creating a non-clustered index with both fields in it (`UserSettingsUserId, UserPasswordRequestHash`), but SQL Server ignored it. Currently it seems to being using an Index Scan of `IX_CMS_UserSettings` and doing nested loops with the key lookup operator to return all the fields on the table (because of the `select *`).

`IX_CMS_UserSettingUserId` contains the field: UserSettingUserId asc

`PK_CMS_UserSetting` is clustered key with `UserSettingId` (note: not the `UserSettingUserId`).

I cannot change the query, only the indexes.

If I change the query to an 'and' instead of an OR it's instant.

edit: In response to some of the comments below, there are already some indexes on the table in question, each in the image includes the column of the same name only:
[image: indexes on table]

Also including all the columns would be undesirable since there are about 50.
The table has 1,239,541 rows.

Also, UserPasswordRequestHash is 'Null' 95% of the time.

Comment: TOP 1 with no ORDER BY? So you don't care which row you get, then?

Comment: Unfortunately, while I agree it's silly, this query comes from the ORM of an off the shelf CMS... such is life.

Comment: Can you explain why it's an OR? Or why it needs to be SELECT *? (You might get the feeling that I'm hinting that ORMs are far from perfect and often tie your hands behind your back both feature- and performance-wise. You wouldn't be wrong.)

Comment: Basically, this query comes from code I cannot easily change. It would be much easier to issue two queries using one part of the predicate and it would return in milliseconds. I'm trying to look at this purely from the standpoint of, "Could I through indexing alone influence SQL server to run this much faster." Basically hands off from the API side. As it stands, this query takes 3 minutes (insanity).

Comment: The key lookup is the biggest cost, so could you INCLUDE all of the other columns in IX_CMS_UserSettings? (This will get rid of the key lookup, but will obviously increase the cost of the scan.) Or change the clustered index to suit that pattern better, and have the primary key non-clustered? Or somehow coerce the ORM to believe that you only need a subset of the columns? How many rows are actually returned here (without the TOP 1 obviously)?

Comment: Another option you could test out if you need to optimize this query and are not concerned with the overhead of adding non-clustered indexes on `cms_usersettings` is to add two indexes, one on `UserSettingUserId` and another on `UserPasswordRequestHash`.  This might allow SQL Server to efficiently identify the rows (or probably just one row) for each predicate and then concatenate those results before needing to perform any join or key lookup.

Comment: Are all of those indexes single-column indexes? Those aren't going to help very many queries at all.

Comment: yes, today is really my first day looking at this (makeshift dba), these indexes were auto-generated by the ORM layer of the CMS.

Comment: You have an `OR` between columns of 2 tables (that are LEFT joined). Your query is basically equivalent to `select top 1 * 
from (select *
from cms_user
LEFT outer join cms_usersettings
    on cms_user.UserId = cms_usersettings.UserSettingsUserId where UserId = 1234 UNION select *
from cms_user
INNER join cms_usersettings
    on cms_user.UserId = cms_usersettings.UserSettingsUserId where UserPasswordRequestHash = 'anxazno121o3n') x;` No wonder the optimizer cannot easily use indexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Could I through indexing alone influence SQL server to run this much faster.*

Possibly.

There are all sorts of things you *could* try with indexing, including creating a filtered index to exclude the 95% of `UserPasswordRequestHash` entries that are null, expanding existing indexes to include more columns, or adjusting indexes so the chances of finding the first match is likely to occur earlier.

The query optimizer does not currently have the ability to explore separating the `OR` predicates into a `UNION ALL`, pushing each predicate below a local `TOP (1)` as a human query writer might naturally do.

It also has to make assumptions about the distribution of data to assess the chances of finding the first match, as mentioned above. In addition, there are all sorts of ways that the optimizer's calculations could be 'off', leading to it selecting the 'wrong' index strategy. Not being able to push index hints through a view also limits the opportunities for using a query hint via a plan guide, for example.

So, the best answer I can give from the information given is "possibly".

If you want a more concrete answer to your question, please supply complete DDL for the tables and indexes, and scripts for the existing statistics. Also, let us know how many logical processors, and how much memory, the instance is configured to use. I realize that is a lot of detail to provide, but a specific answer likely does depend on one or more of these details.

Comment: Yes, and truthfully that answers the question in a way, since it was mainly a sanity check to determine there wasn't some obvious indexing strategy that the query engine would instantly use. It's basically just a bad query, exacerbated by a reasonable table size.